# Avoid SOQL inside for - loop

Tags: apex, soql

How can i optimize this code in order to avoid select within the for-loop? I select some services. Those services have some ids and also a related Service. I want to select all the related services and update them, but i would like to avoid the use of soql inside the for-loop since it is against salefsorce best practices. How could i utilize the maps? Any ideas?

```
//27/11/20 @ggalaios: Function to decrease the number of free consulting services from the related service if free consulting services are used     
    public static List<csord__Service__c> decreaseFreeConsulting(csordtelcoa.OrderGenerationObservable observableContext, Object args){
        try{
            //initiate the list of Services to be updated
            List <csord__Service__c> servicesToUpdate = new List<csord__Service__c>();
            List<Id> serviceIds = observableContext.getServiceIds();
            //Query Specification - get all fields from Service Object & filter with the records in observable context
            String queryString = 'select ' +
            CustomButtonSynchronizeWithOpportunity.getSobjectFields('csord__Service__c') + 
                ' from csord__Service__c where id in :serviceIds';
            system.debug('After query specification');
            //Execute the query
            List<csord__Service__c> servicesList = Database.query(queryString);
            system.debug('After query execution');
            //Iterate through each service selected
            for (csord__Service__c currentService : servicesList) {
                system.debug('currentService is: ' +currentService);
                if (currentService.el_Use_Free_Consulting_Session__c) //Service using free consulting Session
                    if(currentService.el_Related_Service__c != null) { //verify related service is not null
                        csord__Service__c relatedService = [select id, el_Number_of_Free_Consulting_Sessions__c from csord__Service__c
                                                           where id= :currentService.el_Related_Service__c];
                        if(relatedService.el_Number_of_Free_Consulting_Sessions__c > 0) {
                            relatedService.el_Number_of_Free_Consulting_Sessions__c -= 1;
                            servicesToUpdate.add(relatedService);
                        }
                    }
            }
            update servicesToUpdate; //Perform DML Operation to update Related Services...
            return servicesToUpdate; //Return the list of newly updated Services
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new AfterOrderGeneratedObserverException('Services decrease free consulting update failed due to :  ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is collect your filter values outside the loop.

```
Set<Id> relatedServiceIds = new Set<Id>();
for (csord__Service__c service : servicesList)
    relatedServiceIds.add(service.el_Related_Service__c);
Map<Id, csord__Service__c> relatedServices = new Map<Id, csord__Service__c>([
    SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Id IN :relatedServiceIds
]);
for (csord__Service__c service : servicesList)
{
    csord__Service__c relatedService = relatedServices.get(service.el_Related_Service__c);
    // process as before
}
```

Alternatively, since this is a parent object in this lookup relationship, simply add the related fields to your initial query. Here's how the query would look if that's all you were pulling:

```
SELECT el_Related_Service__r.el_Number_of_Free_Consulting_Sessions__c 
FROM csord__Service__c
```

Just add that field path and you can get this data without any extra queries whatsoever.

Comment: Excellent, thanks so much Adrian:)